# How to reuse in SQL the average calculated for a column in a different column?

Tags: sql

What I would like to do is calculate the average value of a specific column, then use that number and substract it from each entry of another column.

Let's consider a first column (Col_1) that contains two possible values (e.g. TypeA and TypeB). The idea is to calculate the average value of the second column (Col_2) for TypeA and then substract that number from each entry of a third column (Col_3) where the Col_1 value is TypeB.

In SQL, I came up with that query:

```
Select T1.Col_1
      ,T2.Avg1
      ,Case When T1.Col_1 = 'TypeB' Then T1.Col_3 - T2.Avg1 End as New_Col_3
from Table1 as T1

Inner Join
(
Select Case When Col_1 = 'TypeA' Then avg(Col_2) End as Avg1
From T1
Group by Col_1
) as T2 on T1.Col_1 = T2.Col_1
```

The issue is that Avg1 is NULL when Col_1 value is TypeB, so basically it doesn't work.

How can I reuse Avg1 and get to the result I need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is easier with window functions:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when t1.col_1 = 'TypeB'
             then t1.col_3 - avg(case when t1.col_1 = 'TypeA' then t1.col_2 end) over ()
        end) as new_col_3
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

DO it this way, calculate both in the subquery

```
Select T1.Col_1
      ,T2.AvgA
      ,T2.AvgA - T2.AvgB
from Table1 as T1

Inner Join
(
Select Col_1,
       Case When Col_1 = 'TypeA' Then avg(Col_2) End as AvgA,
       Case When Col_1 = 'TypeB' Then avg(Col_2) End as AvgB
From Table1 T1
Group by Col_1
) as T2 on T1.Col_1 = T2.Col_1
```